# How to join column values in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

How can I join values in columns with the same name in MultiIndex pandas DataFrame?

```
data = [['1','1','2','3','4'],['2','5','6','7','8']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id','A','B','A','B'])
df = df.set_index('id')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('result','A'),('result','B'),('student','A'),('student','B')])

df
   result    student   
        A  B       A  B
id                     
1       1  2       3  4
2       5  6       7  8
```

Desired results:

```
        A       B
id                     
1       "1 3"   "2 4"
2       "5 7"   "6 8"
```

Comment: you can try `swaplevel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer:

For join values by second level of `MultiIndex` in columns use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
#select columns define in list
df = df[['result','student']]
df1 = df.astype(str).groupby(level=1, axis=1).agg(' '.join)
print (df1)
      A    B
id          
1   1 3  2 4
2   5 7  6 8
```

Old answer:

You can use [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for sorting columns and then [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) for remove first level of `MultiIndex`.

But get duplicate columns names.

```
print (df)
   result    student    col   
        A  B       A  B   A  B
id                            
1       1  2       3  4   6  7
2       5  6       7  8   2  1

#select columns define in list
df = df[['result','student']]
print (df)
   result    student   
        A  B       A  B
id                     
1       1  2       3  4
2       5  6       7  8

df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
print (df)
    A  A  B  B
id            
1   1  3  2  4
2   5  7  6  8
```

So better, unique columns names can be created by `map` with `join`:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
    result_A  student_A  result_B  student_B
id                                          
1          1          3         2          4
2          5          7         6          8
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df['result'],df['student']], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
    A  A  B  B
id            
1   1  3  2  4
2   5  7  6  8
```

Comment: I want to join the values based on column name

Comment: Please check last edit. Is not problem get duplicate columns names?

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure what you are asking. If you have two separate dataframes then you should be able to just use `pd.concat`.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

If you have one dataframe then just drop the top level of the index.

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Comment: `pd.concat([df['result'],df['student']], axis=1)` or `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)` result
`        A  B  A  B`
`    id            `
`    1   1  2  3  4`
`    2   5  6  7  8`